# MergeAdapter and a ClassCastException (with LinearLayout$LayoutParams and AbsListView$LayoutParams)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, classcastexception

I am trying to make my entire layout, which contains a `ListView` scrollable. That is, the entire layout should own the scrollbar rather than just the `ListView`. I'm trying to use commonsguy's `MergeAdapter` (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) but I don't think I'm implementing it correctly since I'm getting the following error:

```
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1872)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1841)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:742)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2431)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at     android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:690)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1183)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4863)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-07 11:05:20.431: E/AndroidRuntime(24474):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's the class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Navigable {

private ListView mHomeList;
private String[] mHomeListStrings = {"lorem","ipsum","loremm","ipsumm"};
private Integer[] mImageIds = {null, null, null, null};
private MergeAdapter mMergeAdapter;

public HomeFragment() { }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //Set string spannable
    String s= "Name\nBusiness";
    SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(s);
    ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0,4, 0); // set size
    TextView tv= (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_header);
    tv.setText(ss1); 

    //Set up list view
    mHomeList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
    ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), mHomeListStrings, mImageIds);

    //I'm doing something wrong either here, or with my xml layout (I think)
    mMergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter();
    mMergeAdapter.addView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_header));
    mMergeAdapter.addAdapter(adapter);
    mMergeAdapter.addView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.apply_button));

    mHomeList.setAdapter(mMergeAdapter);

    return rootView;

}
}
```

My layout for the fragment is below (I took out item attributes to make it shorter):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.xxxx.core.HomeFragment" 
android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/home_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/home_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2">
    </ListView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/apply_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.30"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make sure you are defining height & width for all views ??

Comment: @Soumil, Added the log cat; ρяσѕρєя K, all the views have a defined height and width - i'll add them to the code I posted.

Comment: Oops I just noticed, could the problem be that my items have a defined `layout_weight`, and a `layout_width` of `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting a `ListView` inside `ScrollView` you should try to add header and footer to the list.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter

Simple put view from top of the list and bottom of the list to different xml layouts.

Put only list view inside above layout and in JAVA, inflate these a layouts and add as header and footer respectively.

In case of `MergeAdapter` try to put your header(`TextView`) and footer(`Button`) in different xmls and inflate it, instead of using from same xml.

Comment: Isn't that what `MergeAdapter` is doing internally?

Comment: I'll try to put them in different xml files and post back.

Comment: sorry did not see your code. I think the problem is once you put textview and button in xml they become LinearLayout's subviews and layout param is set as linear layout's layout param. Try to add new Textview and button instead.

Comment: You were right, adding a `new TextView` and `new Button` did the trick.